# Understanding scikitlearn PCA.transform function in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

so I'm currently working on a project that involves the use of Principal Component Analysis, or PCA, and I'm attempting to kind of learn it on the fly. Luckily, Python has a very convenient module from scikitlearn.decomposition that seems to do most of the work for you. Before I really start to use it though, I'm trying to figure out exactly what it's doing.

The dataframe I've been testing on looks like this:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  1
2  4  6
3  5  3
```

And when I call PCA.fit() and then view the components I get:

```
array([[ 0.5172843 ,  0.85581362],
   [ 0.85581362, -0.5172843 ]])
```

From my rather limited knowledge of PCA, I kind of grasp how this was calculated, but where I get lost is when I then call PCA.transform. This is the output it gives me:

```
array([[-2.0197033 , -1.40829634],
       [-1.84094831,  0.8206152 ],
       [ 2.95540408, -0.9099927 ],
       [ 0.90524753,  1.49767383]])
```

Could someone potentially walk me through how it takes the original dataframe and components and transforms it into this new array? I'd like to be able to understand the exact calculations it's doing so that when I scale up I'll have a better sense of what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you call fit PCA is going to compute some vectors that you can project your data onto in order to reduce the dimension of your data. Since each row of your data is 2 dimensional there will be a maximum of 2 vectors onto which data can be projected and each of those vectors will be 2-dimensional. Each row of `PCA.components_` is a single vector onto which things get projected and it will have the same size as the number of columns in your training data. Since you did a full PCA you get 2 such vectors so you get a 2x2 matrix. The first of those vectors will maximize the variance of the projected data. The 2nd will maximize the variance of what's left after the first projection. Typically one passed a value of `n_components` that's less than the dimension of the input data so that you get back fewer rows and you have a wide but not tall `components_` array.

When you call `transform` you're asking sklearn to actually do the projection. That is, you are asking it to project each row of your data into the vector space that was learned when `fit` was called. For each row of the data you pass to `transform` you'll have 1 row in the output and the number of columns in that row will be the number of vectors that were learned in the `fit` phase. In other words, the number of columns will be equal to the value of `n_components` you passed to the constructor.

Typically one uses PCA when the source data has lots of columns and you want to reduce the number of columns while preserving as much information as possible. Suppose you had a data set with 100 rows and each row had 500 columns. If you constructed a PCA like `PCA(n_components = 10)` and then called `fit` you'd find that `components_` has 10 rows, one for each of the components you requested, and 500 columns as that's the input dimension. If you then called `transform` all 100 rows of your data would be projected into this 10-dimensional space so the output would have 100 rows (1 for each in the input) but only 10 columns thus reducing the dimension of your data.

The short answer to how this is done is that PCA computes a Singular Value Decomposition and then keeps only some of the columns of one of those matrices. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) has much more information on the actual linear algebra behind this - it's a bit long for a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Fantastic, that's a big help in understanding what's actually going on. I'll definitely check out Wikipedia to see what that has to say about PCA as well. Thanks!